# sIFR3 show text while loading

Tags: sifr, typography

I am using sIFR3 on a website. I remember in sIFR2 you coul use this sIFR.bHideBrowserText = false; to show the text before sIFR kicks in.

How do you do this in sIFR3 and where do you put the code?

Thanks for your help.

C

Answer (score 0):

The feature as it existed in sIFR 2 no longer exists in sIFR 3. You could achieve the same affect like this, though:

```
sIFR.autoInitialize = false;
sIFR.activate(movie);
sIFR.removeFlashClass();

sIFR.replace(movie, { selector: 'h1' });

window.onload = function(){
  sIFR.setFlashClass();
  sIFR.initialize();
};
```

Where, of course, `movie` is the appropriate variable that references the Flash movie. You might want to connect to the `onload` event through another JavaScript framework. You *must* wait until full page load, things like `$(document).ready()` (jQuery) will *not* work reliably cross-browser.